# istringstream-function string_to_int cannot take c-str, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-strings, istringstream

I learned a helper function that can convert strings to integers:

```
int string_to_int(string s)
{
    istringstream instr(s);
    int n;
    instr>>n;
    return n;
}
```

It's mentioned that the argument s cannot be c-str string, why is this the case?

Comment: Complete example please and don't assume headers. It seems that you're having an implicit `#include<string>`, `#include<sstream>` and `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0):

But you *can* pass a C style string.

The reason for that is because the `std::string` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) can implicitly accept a `CharT*` (Char type, which is `char` in this case) as a parameter. Thus, something like the following would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int string_to_int(string s)
{
    istringstream instr(s);
    int n;
    instr>>n;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    const char* test = "12345";
    std::cout << string_to_int(test) << "\n"; // Outputs 12345
    std::cout << string_to_int("122") << "\n"; // Outputs 122
}
```